# how to prevent directory access and show forbidden error in php

Tags: php, apache

1. I am new to .htaccess, i want to know how to use .htacces to prevent direct access via url of my folder e.g. localhost/mycart/images/ OR localhost/mycart/css should show forbidden message.
2. currently i've put index.php in every folder of my website and echo the messages is it good way to do it.
3. when i access my website like www.mycart/index.php/css or www.mycart/index.php/images it show website without images and css why and how to fix it?

Comment: #3: Why do you care? Why would anyone ever do that and then complain about it? The reason why this happens is that `foo.php/whatever` will still call `foo.php` but for the browser it will look like you are in a folder called `foo.php` and thus any relative links will not work.

Comment: is there any way to prevent it ?
asking about foo.php/whatever showing page without css just for knowledge!

Comment: `if(!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) { header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); exit; }`. If you don't need it at all you can also put `AcceptPathInfo Off` in your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have used

```
# disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes
```

Conversely, to enable directory browsing, use the following directive:

```
# enable directory browsing
Options +Indexes
```

Likewise, this rule will prevent the server from listing directory contents:

```
# prevent folder listing
IndexIgnore *
```

And, finally, the IndexIgnore directive may be used to prevent the display of select file types:

```
# prevent display of select file types
IndexIgnore *.wmv *.mp4 *.avi *.etc
```

Courtesy From:  [Prevent Unauthorized Directory Browsing](http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#sec3) from [Stupid HTACCESS Tricks](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/).

It also contains many other useful commands to be used in `.htaccess` for security and performance enhancement.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply add the following to your .htaccess

```
# Don't listing directory
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.your-website-home-page.com/
# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Default handler
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This will load only the index.php file while file browsing. If no index.php file is found 403 error happens (Access restricted) and it will send the user to home page

Answer (score 9):

If you want to deny access to all files:

```
deny from all
```

If you want to disable directory listing:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: when i use deny from all , i can't open any part of my website. so why this option is used