# How do I make folders Forbidden to view in Magento

Tags: html, mysql, sql-server, apache, magento

Example:  http://www.acuity-sports.com/skin/

I want this to be what they see below instead of my tree:

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /skin on this server.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look @ [how to prevent directory access and show forbidden error in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773025/how-to-prevent-directory-access-and-show-forbidden-error-in-php)

Add a .htaccess file with

```
# disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

There many ways to do so - a) apache vhost fole b) .htaccess

If u want follow (b), do following in .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

Thanks